# Android. ActiveJDBC possible?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, activejdbc, javalite

Official web site says that library supports SQLite 3. Android has SQLite. 
Is it possible to use [JavaLite's ActiveJDBC](http://javalite.io/activejdbc) in Android Studio project?

Website says that conenction is made like this:

```
   Base.open("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "the_user", "the_password");
   Employee.findAll().dump();
   Base.close();
```

In the case of Android, how to connect library to SQLite database?

Answer (score 2):

According to this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/package-summary.html, there is JDBC support on Android now, but if you take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/DriverManager.html it states: "...Android does not include any JDBC drivers by default; you must provide your own."

Quick googling for Android SQLite JDBC drivers brought up some dead projects, so I assume this not possible simply because there are no drivers available. The framework itself would probably work if there was a driver.